# join(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given

Tags: php, xampp, doctrine, symfony5

So I am a beginner working on a project with symfony 5.2 project with php 8, and I have been trying to run this command

```
symfony console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

And this is the error I get :

> In Lorem.php line 95:
> join(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given

Comment: Please show us line 95 from Lorem.php

Comment: I have the same issue, did you fix it?

Answer (score 16):

Check the line 95 of Lorem.php, you will find:

`return join($words, ' ') . '.';`

change to:

```
return join(' ', $words) . '.';
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you.

Comment: It didn't generate error on PHP 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2, whereas it did with PHP 8.1 on Windows 10. So nice to find the solution here!